# how to show/display real time data in react js my using external javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, reactjs, webassembly, emscripten

i am working on a project i which i used c++,javascript,Emscripten.
**

### C++ part

In my c++ part i have struct alike

```
struct Person
    {
       int name;
       string type;
       .
       .
    }
```

So for generating person data i made a function which sets values and return object

### Web Assembly or Emscripten

So for sending and using c++ in javascript on frontend i used emscripten.

It perfectly working.Data is generating from c++ and displaying in console in js/html file (only in console)

### Problems i am facing right now:

1- data in not showing in real time on html page.When all data reloads then it shows on html(i also tried approach of async and script tag up and down in body of html)
2- How i can use this tag and data in displayed in real time in my react app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a websocket server for showing data in realtime. If you dont know how to make a websocket server you can try socket io its simpler for beginners and works well for small projects.
Socket io for cpp -https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp

Comment: i do not want to make websocket becuase i need speed .and i think web socket will slow down my data streaming

Comment: Websocket is the fastest way to show data in realtime, I dont think you can show data in realtime without websocket and why did someone downvote my post if there is any other way of showing data in realtime let me know aswell.

Comment: so according to you first of all c++ data moves to nodes js and then to react js.am i right.

Comment: Nah you can directly make a websocket server in c++ and use fetch or axios in reactjs to get a websocket server running without nodejs.